# dxBarManager - icon not displaying on dxBarLargeButton1

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am using dxBarManager1. To it, I assigned cxImageList1.
I added an icon of appropriate size in cxImageList1 and tried (on formshow):

> dxBarLargeButton1.LargeImageIndex := 0;

But it will not show.
Why ?

The code is simple :

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ImgList, cxGraphics, dxBar,
  cxClasses;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    dxBarManager1: TdxBarManager;
    dxBarManager1Bar1: TdxBar;
    dxBarLargeButton1: TdxBarLargeButton;
    cxImageList1: TcxImageList;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
dxBarLargeButton1.LargeImageIndex := 0;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't set correct size for ImageList, maybe you didn't set correct size for button (LargeButton can be displayed in both sizes), ... There are a lot of possibilities. If you provide full example, then it will be possible to help you. But i believe you can solve it yourself, DEX comes with tons of examples, just have look at one and compare with your code. You can also search support area of DEX site, there are lot of discussed problems/situations with demo projects.

Comment: I made double sure the icon is of appropriate size. To make it more 'secure' I even used devexpress icon for the occasion. Maybe dxBarManager1 has to refresh somehow...Don't know.

Comment: It is not enough. You did all settings in design time, not in the code. Provide DFM file at least, or (perfectly) make all assignments from the code. Maybe you assigned image list to ImageOptions.Images instead of ImageOptions.LargeImages for exmaple.

Comment: If you'd shown an MCVE, nobody would have had to guess

Comment: @David Heffernan  what's a MCVE ????

Comment: @user3181689 You can type that into Google if you want to know. That really is one of the most important skills to learn.

Comment: I assume he means " Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example".  However, all the code (MCVE)  is already shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign something to your bar manager `LargeImages` property.

```
dxBarManager1.ImageOptions.LargeImages := cxImageList1;
```